# Spring application showing intermittent delays in responding to requests

Tags: java, tomcat, networking, amazon-ec2, spring-boot

I have a Spring application (using SpringBoot version 1.3.6.RELEASE) installed on 5 EC instances (m4.4xlarge) running behind a Nginx proxy. All the instances are running Ubuntu 14.04.

I start the application using `java -jar API-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar  -Xms8192m -Xmx16384m -Djava.net.preferIPv4Stack=true -Djava.net.preferIPv4Addresses`

When I query the API from one of the local instances, to ensure the instance is up and running, an intermittent delay of up to 4 seconds is shown before the application responds to the request. The request is launched from the local instance to the local instance.

To invoke the API I execute `DATE=$(date +"%Y%m%d%H%M%S"); echo $DATE; curl -XGET http://xxxx:9998/api/ping --header "Content-Type:application/json"` (where xxxx is the private IP address of the instance). The `api/ping` endpoint just returns a value of pong and does not touch a database or file system.

The access logs for the embedded Tomcat also show the delay in handling the request.

[image: access log]

The tcpdump looks as follows which also reflects the delay on the port.

[image: tcpdump]

What I have tried

- TCPv6 is disabled on the instance I am testing
- The net.ipv4.tcp_fin_timeout parameter is set to 30
- Let the embedded Tomcat server listen on a specific address (not *)
- Tried to extend the number of minimum number of threads for Tomcat
- Increase the timeout values for the Tomcat server

The API responds consistently on my local development machine (of course it does!)

The problem is the intermittent delays in handling the requests. The speed of the API response is inside acceptable parameters, but the intermittent delay is causing a massive delay in the API response times.

--- **UPDATE 20/9**

I managed to simulate the issue on my local machine. If the application is run using `mvn spring-boot:run`, no delay is seen when invoking the API. However, when the application is started using `java -jar API-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar` the delay is seen.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this with a spring-boot service I maintain.

I read our logs back to the point where the high latency started, and narrowed it down to the moment we updated `tomcat-embed-jasper` from version 8.0.26 to version 8.0.36.

I can't tell you exactly why it's doing that, but when we rolled back, our delays were gone immediately.

Comment: Thanks I will have a look. We ended up installed the spring-boot application inside a stand alone tomcat installation

Answer (score 0):

Recent Tomcat changed how `hostname` information obtained in `RemoteIpValve`. That cause the long delay on each request. Adjust `/etc/hosts` may help, I decided to use Undertow instead.